# System.ServiceModel WCF Service Mono missing framework

Tags: .net, wcf, mono

but i have looked all over the internet and no one seems to be having this problem.
I'm trying to connect to my Windows WCF Service using mono (4.0 framework).

however when i'm writing my program and i type `using System.ServiceModel` it cant find it...
i guess im just doing something really stupid but can someone show me what?! :P

Comment: Have you referenced `System.ServiceModel.dll`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reference `System.ServiceModel.dll` :)